# How to hook only the card which is clicked to grow open and reset the previously clicked card to go-back to closed using react functional hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have 3 cards. Each card open and close respectively when clicked on it. I want to hook such that when i click one card the other card (previously clicked card) should get closed.

I think it can be done by using it's id, but i don't know how & where to hook to make it work. A sandbox would really be helpful.

Link to the Sandbox.. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/grf-component-jq6jk)

My code is as below:

```
//App.jsx

    import React from "react";
    import Card from "./Card";
    import data from "../data";
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <div>
          {data.map((data, index) => {
            return (
              <Card
                key={data.id}
                id={data.id}
                title={data.title}
                img={data.image}
                description={data.description}
                specification={data.specification}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;

//Card.jsx

import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function CatCard(props) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

  return (
    <div
      className="catWrapper"
      style={{ backgroundColor: isOpen ? "#fffbc7" : "#fff" }}
    >
      <div
        className="catContainer"
        onClick={toggle}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: isOpen ? "#fffbc7" : "#fff",
          paddingBottom: isOpen ? "20px" : "0"
        }}
      >
        <div className="catDetails">
          <h1>{props.title}</h1>
          <p>{props.description}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="catButton">
          <button
            style={{
              transform: isOpen ? "rotate(-90deg)" : "rotate(90deg)"
            }}
          >
            &#x276F;
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        className="catContent"
        style={{ display: isOpen ? "block" : "none" }}
      >
        <p>{props.specification}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this into `CatCard.jsx` file.

```
const { activeIdx, idx, handleClick } = props;

const toggle = () => {
  handleClick(idx)
}

React.useEffect(() => {
  setIsOpen(activeIdx === idx);
}, [activeIdx, idx])
```

And add this to your `App.jsx` file.

```
const [activeIdx, setActiveIdx] = React.useState(-1);
const isClicked = (idx) => {
  setActiveIdx(idx);
};

return (
  <div>
    {data.map((data, index) => {
      return (
        <Card
          key={data.id}
          idx={index}
          id={data.id}
          activeIdx={activeIdx}
          title={data.title}
          img={data.image}
          description={data.description}
          specification={data.specification}
          handleClick={isClicked}
        />
      );
    })}
  </div>
);
```

Basically, you create a new variable `activeIdx` (or you can call it `expandedCardIdx`. Whatever you like) to keep track of the the `active` card, assuming there can only be one. The click event in the `CatCard.jsx` will update the `App.tsx` state, and propagate the new `active` card `idx` to all cards. If the `index` of the card matches the `active` index, then it will be expanded. Otherwise, it will be collapsed.

The `useEffect` hook updates the `isOpen` state whenever `activeIdx` or `idx` props change. There is no need to "clear" the `useEffect` hook. Not too sure what you mean by "clear".

`[activeIdx, idx]` is the dependency array, where you include `state` or `props` values to instruct the hook to run each time any of these values update. See more info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

Comment: Yes sir, you are correct.. it can be done your way. I have a doubt, do i need to clear the useEffect..? I don't know much about useEffect as i'm still learing. Can u kindly brief me on what the useEffect is doing.. as i understand it is checking for the correct idx to match with the activeIdx, but what is  --> [activeIdx, idx] ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the last paragraph. Also added link to the documentation. If in doubt, look it up via the link.

Comment: Yeah.. sorry.! its clean up nor 'clear". I just read somewhere.. like we to to clean up so that we don’t introduce a memory leak! while using useEffect..  just asked as i'm lagging knowledge on it. Thank you for explaining it & for the link Sir. It really did solve my issue. Thank you..!

Comment: Cleaning up is only required if you are adding an event listener or subscribing to some external topics. Therefore, in order to prevent memory leak, you will need to return a function that unsubscribes from the event listener or external topics.